# RSpec Controller Testing - "assigns" behaving unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bdd, rspec-rails

I have built out a controller spec for my user model, and it passes, although I feel like it should fail.  The spec is below:

```
describe UsersController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  let (:user) do
    FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end
  let (:other_user) do
    FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

  before :each do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    sign_in user
  end

  describe "#index" do
    it "can GET 'index'" do
      get :index
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "populates a list of users" do
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:users)).to eq([user])
    end
  end
end
```

The line "expect(assigns(:users)).to eq([user])" passes, but I feel like it should fail.  After all, I've created two users (user and other_user) up at the top.  I'm clearly misunderstanding what's going on, so can someone explain it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`let` is lazy; it won't create the user until the first time it's called (at which point the result is memoized). Since you call `user` but not `other_user`, only the first user is actually created, and the spec passes.

Use `let!` if you want eager evaluation, or make sure you call `other_user` somewhere.

[RSpec Documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let)

Comment: Thank you so much for that!  It was driving me crazy.